# How to integrate HDFC payment gateway in magento?

Tags: payment-gateway

After exhaustive search over the net I decided to post this question. The previous integration I have done had modules in magento E-commerce. I have no idea how to integrate HDFC payment gateway.Please help if anyone had did this before. Even a guidance or small instruction would help. Thank you.

Comment: how about creating a new payment method and integrating it with HDFC, ofcourse you will have to get the details about how there api works. 
check it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12442/custom-payment-gateway-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an extension available on MagentoConnect:

[HDFC Payment Gateway](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/hdfc-payment-gateway.html)

Alternately, looking at this thread:

http://www.easycommerce.in/blog/hdfc-payment-gateway-for-magento-ecommerce-business/

**The module is no longer on their site**. You could try contacting them & asking if it's still available

And as a final resort:

There's a comment by `Mahesh`:

> thanks easy commerce for helping us out on integrating for our clients, the module works seamlessly , HDFC has released dual verification system , and it would have taken us about 2 - 3 weeks to deliver the site to our client, your timely support and module has helped us launch the site immediately. hdfc bank had to just run the test once and they confirmed everything was in place immediately.

Contact the bank directly & ask them how their other clients integrate with them when running Magento.

Comment: I have mailed the bank regarding the same. Is it possible to code inside magento so as to take parameters required or something like that in custom. Or some tutorials for same. I guess thats how it has to be done.

Comment: I think with something like a payment gateway you'd really rather not reinvent the wheel due to security purposes. It'll be a big task to do this on your own.

Comment: Got reply from the bank. They said they don't support magento. Now left it on client to decide. I will accept this answer as it did show me some way.

Comment: Ah yeah, good luck. I hope your client decides against them then. If a bank is too lazy to develop a payment gateway for one of the biggest e-commerce platforms in the industry, I wouldn't want to work with them. @Keyul Shah 's option seems to be the go-to alternative.

Comment: @Moose Can i get magent 1 extension link.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this [Magento 2 HDFC Extension](https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-hdfc-payments.html) for integrating HDFC Payment Gateway with Magento 2. You can also ask for Magento 1 version.